# assigning uiimage to imageview

Tags: ios, uiimage, imageview

I'm not able execute a very simple statement. Its been frustrating one hour.

```
self.mainImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Radio"];
```

I've tried `[self.mainImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Radio"]];`

The connections are all fine. And there is already an image assigned to this. I need to change the image assigned to this view.

Tried various permutations with `[UIImage imageNamed:@"Radio.png"];`

Also tried Allocating the image first and then assigning it to image view.

Comment: When you allocate the image first, what does NSLog say? `NSLog(@"%@",[UIImage imageNamed:@"Radio.png"]);` Also, try `NSLog(@"%@",self.mainImageView);` Because there is no doubt one of them will prove to be failing. That's how to debug this sort of thing. No need to thrash around. Just test logically! We've all made mistakes along these lines; we all make them all the time. All that's happened here is that you got frustrated and didn't take a deep breath and test.

Comment: Thanks Matt for being patient with me. I got that figured out. Apologies for posting question without trying this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is one of two reasons:

a) The imageView is not connected in interface builder, which I assume you are using, and is therefore uninitialised

b) The image doesn't exist in the application's bundle.

In order to check which reason refers to you, try running an `NSLog(@"%@", self.mainImageView);` to see if it is a), and alternatively, NSLog the image before creation, and check that the file exists in the File Organiser (the left hand menu) in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks. the image was not in bundle. The proper logging did the trick.